# assertEqual doesn't print unequal objects

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.3, python-unittest

So I've got some methods returning some rather complex objects, and I'd like to test this output. I construct a unit test using `unittest`, and I find that the computed object and the expected object I constructed aren't equal. Too bad.

What gets me though, is that the error message doesn't print the two objects, only some bland `repr`. Each object defines `__str__` and `__eq__`, and I know that the `__str__`, as verified by placing a `raise ValueError` in the `__str__` function.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many places in Python use the `repr()` of an object instead of the `str()` as the `repr()` usually specifies one exact instance.

If you want to see the actual `str()` instead, many assertWhatever methods allow a custom error message:

```
assertEqual(my_obj1, my_obj2, '%s != %s' % (my_obj1, my_obj2))
```